# Unable to update Netbeans 7.1 to 7.2

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I am having netbeans 7.1. When I am trying to update it, it says "Your IDE is upto date!". But you know, 7.1.2 and 7.2 are there!!! I thought this is because of an error in update channels.

However, I yesterday install C++ and hit "Update" in netbeans. It showed me list of C++ plugins which need to be updated and yes, it updated them too!. Why I am unable to update netbeans to its next version?

Not like days back, now sometimes netbeans shows "No documentation found" when I use intellisence to know what the particular Java method supposed to do. Is this has to do something with the above issue?

And err, when I type "download netbeans" in google, the first link is "Nightly - NetBeans". What is this "Nightly" thing? Please answer to both of questions. Thank you..

Comment: This "nightly thing" is the nightly build. So it's the current (development) status of the project and is only meant for evaluating new features and not for real productive use, since it can contain bugs which might cause data-loss. It's provided so interested persons do not have to check out the sources themselves and compile them on their own.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded it. The reason was Netbeans 7.1 in both of my machines started giving errors, after months of proper use. I believe it is because of an update. However 7.2 seems to work fine :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found following answer in the NetBeans IDE 7.2 Installation Instructions:

> ### Note:
>
> Incremental version upgrades of the IDE cannot be performed at this time. To upgrade to the most recent version you must download the latest installer.

http://netbeans.org/community/releases/72/install.html#upgrading

Answer (score 5):

This is the closest thing to a plain upgrade I have found:

1. download the latest version from http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html
   and run the installer. The installer will detect if you have an older version installed,
   and ask if you want to import configurations from that version.
2. When you launch the new version of the IDE it will automatically detect plugins that were installed in the old version, and ask if you want to install them in the new version (it may not happen within the first couple of minutes after IDE is started, but it does happen eventually).